# Theory behind `curvefit()` module in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Consider I have the following data:

```
0.000000000000000000e+00 4.698409927534825670e-01
1.052631578947368363e+00 8.864688755521996200e+00
2.105263157894736725e+00 1.554529316011567630e+01
3.157894736842105310e+00 9.767558170900922931e+00
4.210526315789473450e+00 2.670221074763470881e+01
```

Now, I would like to use this data to do some statistical analysis.

```
%pylab inline
# Loads numpty
my_data = loadtxt("numbers.dat")
dataxaxis = my_data[:,0]
datayaxis = my_data[:,1]
```

I know that I am storing the data as a variable and hence taking the first column as my xdata for the x-axis and the second column as my y data for the y-axis.

I was learning about the `curvefit()` function which works similar to `polyfit()` in finding a Line of best fit (LOBF) gradient and intercept.

I understood that first I had to define the function of a straight line being `y = mx+c`.

Here is where I become confused. 
According to the lecturer, I needed to have the xdata as an argument, but also define the gradient and intercept as parameters:

```
def straightline(dataxaxis, m, c):
    "Returns values of y according to y = mx + c"
    return m*dataxaxis + c
```

And later I could call the `curvefit()` function as such:

```
lineinfo = curve_fit(line, dataxaxis, datayaxis)
lineparams = lineinfo[0]
m = lineparams[0]
c = lineparams[1]
```

which gave the corresponding values.

But, when I called the function `straightline` as the first parameter in `curve_fit`, I didn't pass any information about `dataxaxis` or any information about `m` or `c` yet it still calculated the gradient and intercept to return in a matrix regardless.

How is this possible?

Comment: Are you talking about `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`? Where does your curve fit function come from? Have you read the documentation of that library? There's no builtin `curvefit` function in python.

Comment: @HåkenLid yes it is the same thing I am only using Jupyter's own `numpy` - can you still explain the question using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit?`

Comment: You can pass initial guesses for `m` and `c` to `curve_fit`, see `p0` in the docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html Just because you did not explicitly do so, doesn't mean you didn't pass any. The docs say that if these values are not declared, `1` is used for each parameter.

Comment: @Mr.T then how would it know what `m` and `c` are in the first place?

Comment: You define them in your function? I don't get your question. BTW, it should be `lineinfo = curve_fit(straightline, dataxaxis, datayaxis)` in your example, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Mr.T oh I understand that, but I haven't given it values of `m` and `c` to work with - I only passed it as parameters. so how does it suddenly return the y data points? and yes you're right.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment: You can provide initial values via the parameter `p0`, e.g., for `m = 17` and `c = 23`:  `lineinfo = curve_fit(line, dataxaxis, datayaxis, p0 = (17, 23))`. Your `lineinfo = curve_fit(line, dataxaxis, datayaxis)` omitting this parameter is equivalent to using the preset value 1: `lineinfo = curve_fit(line, dataxaxis, datayaxis, p0 = (1, 1))`. Please read the linked documentation for more information.